# Postgres: how to use LIKE on every word of user input, AND-ing the results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, sql-like

In postgresql (9.6), given a variable length user input of the type 'alice chaplin' or 'alice' or 'alice chaplin meyer' but also 'lic chapl', I would like to search for records that contain 'alice' in column firstname OR column lastname (AND contain 'chaplin' in firstname OR lastname (AND contain 'meyer' in firstname OR lastname)), etc.

I had decided to use `ILIKE %searchterm%` for the matching, so the query would presumably be along the lines of:

```
... where
     ((lastname ILIKE '%' || SEARCHTERM1 || '%') OR (firstname ILIKE '%' || SEARCHTERM1 || '%')) 
 AND ((lastname ILIKE '%' || SEARCHTERM2 || '%') OR (firstname ILIKE '%' || SEARCHTERM2 || '%')) 
 AND etc.
```

After lots of attempts and searching, nothing comes up that resolves this... As a last resort I'll write a very procedural pgplsql function that loops over a split search string, intersecting the `ILIKE` results, but there has to be some more idiomatic SQL way of resolving such a run of the mill problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_to_array` to convert an input string into an array of words. You can then use `unnest` to convert the array into a (virtual) table, and operate on the words to add '%' before and after. And finally, you can use the `ALL` comparison using `ILIKE ALL (SELECT ...)`. This `ALL` will actually be AND-ing the results, as desired.

```
WITH q AS
(
  SELECT 'Alice Chaplin Meyer'::text AS q
)
, words AS
(
SELECT 
  '%' || word || '%' AS wordish
FROM
  q
  JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(q, ' ')) AS a(word) ON true
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t
WHERE
    concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) ILIKE ALL(SELECT wordish FROM words)
```

You can check it all at http://rextester.com/LNB38296

References:

1. [`string_to_array` and `unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)
2. [Using ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21126)

NOTE: This can probably be simplified, but I've prefered a step-by-step approach.

Comment: Thanks, but that leaves me with the same question: how to get from the initial search string (or an array resulting from splitting that search string) to the right amount of AND clauses. Ie. the content of the AND clauses is not the issue, the one I sketched above also works. The issue is how to get from the search string to the ANDs, ie the intersection of the individual results.

Comment: I didn't get your actual question... sorry

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Note that your join is unnecessary, that line can be simplified to: `FROM q, unnest(string_to_array(q, ' ')) AS word)` (I don't think I have enough points to edit your question inline to simplify it) {Note to future readers of the comments above: they are about a previous version of @joanolo's answer, which was totally different.}